# Preserve Order of IN in ORM Order

Tags: phalcon

I'm trying to do a query where I preserve the order of the ids in a IN statement. I can't seem to do it with either the Model Manage Query Builder or the standard ORM 'order' array parameter. Am I missing something? I keep getting:

```
UNEXPECTED TOKEN IDENTIFIER(, NEAR TO 'id`enter code here`,17743,16688,16650
```

Here's my model manager:

```
$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery('SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', array_keys($finalIterations)).')
                    ORDER BY FIELD(id,'.implode(',', array_keys($finalIterations)).'');
```

It's pretty obvious PhQL doesn't like the FIELD key word. Is there a way for me to do what I'm trying to do with PhQL? It seems I will not be able to do what I need to.

Comment: This seems to be a missing feature, it would be better create this is as a bug/feature request on Github

Comment: Thank you! I will do so. I have a couple of things I found that are missing, so I will go ahead and log them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as previously said, this is missing a feature in Phalcon.

Have a look at this function, I've put it into my *ModelBase* abstract class which is parent class of all my models. It uses PhQL variable binding, so it's safe for handling direct user input.

You could have reimplemented custom *\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria* but this solution seems to be easier to work with, at least for me.

---

**ModelBase abstract**

```
public function appendCustomOrder( \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\CriteriaInterface &$criteria, $orderField, array &$orderValues = [] ) {
    if(!empty($orderValues)) {
        $queryKeys = $bindParams = [];
        foreach($orderValues as $key => $id) {
            $queryKey = 'pho'.$key;
            $queryKeys[] = ':'.$queryKey.':';
            $bindParams[$queryKey] = $id;
        }

        // TODO: add support for multiple orderBy fields
        $criteria->orderBy('FIELD('.$orderField.','.implode(',',$queryKeys).')');
        // there's no 'addBind' function, need to merge old parameters with new ones
        $criteria->bind( array_merge( (array) @$criteria->getParams()['bind'], $bindParams ) );
    }
}
```

---

**Controller usage**

```
$projectIDs = [17743, 16688, 16650];
$projectsModel = new Projects();

$criteria = $projectsModel->query->inWhere( 'id', $projectIDs );
$projectsModel->appendCustomOrder( $criteria, 'id', $projectIDs );

$projectsData = $criteria->execute();
```

This will generate valid PhQL syntax similar to this one:

```
SELECT `projects`.`id` AS `id`, `projects`.`title` AS `title` 
FROM `projects` 
WHERE `projects`.`id` IN (:phi0, :phi1, :phi2) 
ORDER BY FIELD(`projects`.`id`, :pho0, :pho1, :pho2)
```

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing in the base Model. Figured there really wasn't a better way for now. It's actually creepy how close this is haha. I didn't have all the field stuff. Thank you so much, though! I greatly appreciate it!